# TFS Edit Build Definition > Process downloading entire solution

Tags: tfsbuild

When I select build definition in TFS and click on the Process Tab, the screen stays on Downloading custom assemblies...

After about 30 seconds it throws an error about a file name that is too long. When I press ok to this error, I have the option to select Show Details and edit the Build process template.

Why does the process template trigger downloading the entire solution to a temp folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your controller mappings for "Version control path to custom assemblies", when you open the process tab in order to work with your template VS in background downloads the custom assembly contents, if your controller setting are pointing to wrong folder or the folder contains items unrelated to build it will download everything.

The specific error comes from limitation of file system path length. Since temp folder is deep itself in folder hierarchy even a simple solution can go over limit.

You can use another instance of visual studio to debug by attaching to instance having the issue you can then look up loaded modules to see what exactly gets loaded from where.

Comment: Thank you. You were right, I had the Version control path to custom assemblies set as the root of my project.